# Watch Netflix with Windows 7 Media Center

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, netflix

Is this possible? I've heard that there's an extension or something for Vista's Media Center, but I can't figure out how to enable this in Windows 7.

Comment: I got it working in Vista, but it took a lot of trial and error so I couldn't tell what finally clicked to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been released for Windows 7 yet. I imagine any attempts to get it working are completely unsupported.

Keep an eye on the [Netflix Blog](http://blog.netflix.com/) for announcements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if [MyNetflix](http://www.anpark.com/software.aspx) works in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using PlayOn, which supports Windows 7. You don't even need PlayOn running on your Windows 7 machine though; it just has to be running on any machine on your network.

It registers itself as a UPnP Media Server, which any UPnP client (which Media Center is, I am almost positive) can access to play your Netflix, Hulu, YouTube, etc etc.

[PlayOn](http://www.themediamall.com/playon)

Answer (score 0):

Netflix is supported in Windows 7 Media center out of the box. 
no 3rd part plugins needed.

Just make sure to run all the Windows 7 updates. When you are done installing all the windows updates, open WMC and the Netflix icon will be there waiting for you.